# Is there a way to get email of some user in the domain without usage of COM?

Tags: c++, windows, email, dns

I found a way to get email address of some principal using ADsGetObject. However, it requires COM.

My app doesn't use COM and I don't want to initialize it, just for the sake of doing one API call.

Have you seen any Windows API which allow to get a user email?

Comment: I suppose that any API doing this thing would internally call `ADsGetObject`, and would either require the caller to initialize COM first, or would initialize COM by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Directory programming requires COM, there is no lower level API.

Looking for alternatives: there is no great advantage to using C++ when dealing with something like email.  It tends to work just as well from a scripting language, the bottleneck is not the language.  Using ADSI from a scripting language (or especially .NET) is quite easy, they have runtime environments that take care of the COM plumbing.

The twenty dollar solution: add the required config instead of trying to read it back from AD.

Comment: got it. yeah... config won't work for me, I need to get emails for different users in runtime, so there is no way to put it in the config beforehand.